# sql server 2008 export to mdb issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i'm trying to import records from a mdb file to sql server 2008. i have a separate db server and application server.

wrote a stored proc to import data from mdb. But it fails as the mdb is on a network. It works if it's on the db server itself.

i'm using sql server account.

if i login using windows account and try the same sp it works.

How to make it work for sql server account?

-Vivek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the SQL Server service running under a domain user account? If not, then it has no means to authenticate to the network share. To correct, you should change the SQL Server service to run under a domain account that has access to the network share. When you login via Windows Authentication, the stored procedure runs under your credentials which have access to the network share.

**ADDITION** Changing the SQL Server service account.

1. Run the SQL Configuration Manager
2. Click on SQL Services
3. Right-click on the SQL Server serice and choose "Properties..."
4. Change the account name to something like `<Domain>\SQLUser`

I would recommend having a dedicated account on the domain for SQL Server with a long password that is kept safe somewhere. The configuration manager should put the user in the appropriate Local User group which will be named something like "SQLServerMSSQLUser$$MSSQLServer" which will give it the necessary rights to run SQL Server as a service and access the files and folders it needs.

For more information:

[Setting Up Windows Service Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx)

Comment: how to make it run under domain user account?